# CSS Need to put Navigation Bar over image

Tags: css, wordpress

I need to have my navigation bar positioned over my header image. 
I cannot use the background url property in CSS as I have multiple navigation bars and header images for different pages.  I would like the navigation to be floated right so it is offset to the image, but partly over the image.

```
            Button 1 | Button 2 | Button 3 | Button 4
Header Image
```

I have tried many ways for example placing them same div and using CSS position absolute on the image. This cases the navigation to stop working. When I use position absolute on the navigation I cannot move the navigation far enough to the right  (right: 200px) cannot move anymore!
Does anyone know how to achieve the desired result as described above? Thanks in advance!
HTML PHP

```
<div id="navigation-container">

 <nav id="np-access" role="navigation">
   <?php if ( (is_page(20) || is_page(22) || is_page(24) || is_page(26) ||    is_page(28)) ) { 
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'third') );
   }else{
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary') );
   }
?>
 </nav>
</div>

<?php if ( (is_page(20) || is_page(22) || is_page(24) || is_page(26) || is_page(28)) )    { 
    echo '<img src="<path ito image" width="194" height="166"/>';
}
else{
   echo '<img src="<path ito image" width="194" height="166"/>';
}
?>
```

At the moment the image is not styled as it is in the position I require.

Navigation CSS

```
#np-wedding-nav{
  float: right;
  padding-right: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like the navigation to be floated right so it is offset to the image, but partly over the image.

Give the navigation a negative margin:

```
nav {margin-left: -100px}
```

Or position is relatively:

```
nav {position: relative; left: -100px}
```

In any case: change the order of both the navigation and the image in the markup.

Comment: Thanks NGLN much appreciated Learnt something there I changed the order!

Answer (score -2):

Kindly change the order in of the header and the nav your html file and it should work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is not really an answer and also does not add anything to the accepted one